# Codeigniter RESTful web api creation for mobile and web applications general guidelines

Tags: php, android, rest, research

I'm having application with running good in codeigniter, mysql and jquery. Currently we are planning to evaluate our web application with mobile application. So we planned to develop web application, android,ios and blackberry. Everything is native application.

For everything we planned to develop codeigniter restfull api(This is server for all the client web and mobiles). 
For web application we planned to develop client with angular js. But every client access web api server only. My codeigniter controller now looks like API.

My question is,
1.Is this good idea to create single server for all the client both web and mobile
2.How to create unique  authentication for both web and mobile apps

Because in web app we have the session but in mobile there is no session. So how to create authentication uniquely for both apps.

I have planned to send a token to client, once login get successful. And then after for each and every request to server, the client will send a token with the request header. I have no idea of how to do the same for mobile apps, as web app having session, and hence we can save the token into session variable in server. But in-case of mobile app, how to create server variable and maintain the tokens.

Please anyone help me to get clarify my doubts.